# How to return the last two values based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the results of the dataset below based on the date of transaction. The example employee was FTE 1.0 but changed to FTE 0.9. How can I do this?

```
with 
HrHist as
(
select *, row_number() over (partition by h.EMPLOYEE order by h.EMPLOYEE, h.BEG_DATE desc) as rownum
from dbo.HRHISTORY h
where h.FLD_NBR = 56 and h.EMPLOYEE = 123

)
select HrHist.EMPLOYEE, 
format(max(HrHst.N_VALUE), '#.00') as currFTE, 
format(min(HrHist.N_VALUE), '#.00') as prevFTE
from HrHist
where rownum <= 2
group by HrHist.EMPLOYEE
```

Result: The current FTE is not 1.0. Its 0.9. I want 0.9 as current and 1.0 as previous. The row numbers can be many but I only care for the last two.

| EMPLOYEE | currFTE | prevFTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1.00 | .90 |

Sample data set:

| row_nbr | COMPANY | EMPLOYEE | OBJ_ID | FLD_NBR | BEG_DATE | N_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10 | 123 | 0 | 56 | 2000-03-27 00:00:00.000 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 10 | 123 | 0 | 56 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00.000 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 10 | 123 | 0 | 56 | 2021-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 0.9 |

Comment: You wrote "FTE" contain values like 1.0 but your query doesn't refer to a column named FTE nor does your sample data set contain one. It does refer to a column named N_VALUE which does not exist in your sample data. Your query also refers to an alias "HRHX" which does not exist. The best way to get help and avoid all these simple errors is to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SMor - I fixed the query to get rid of the typo. The N_VALUE is the FTE. That column holds any data (like a salary change). the FLD_NBR corresponds to what changed and in this case, its the FTE. The FLD_NBR 56 reflects a change in FTE. If you look at my columns alias, you will notice that in this case, I am calling the N_VALUE "fte". Thank you for looking!

Comment: You haven't got `N_VALUE` in your sample data *either*.

Comment: @Charlieface - edited the question to add that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably goes like this:

```
with 
HrHist as
(
select *, row_number() over (partition by h.EMPLOYEE order by h.EMPLOYEE, h.BEG_DATE desc) as rownum
from dbo.HRHISTORY h
where h.FLD_NBR = 56 and h.EMPLOYEE = 123

)
select HrHist.EMPLOYEE, 
format(MAX(CASE WHEN row_nbr = 1 THEN HRHX.N_VALUE END), '#.00') as currFTE, 
format(MAX(CASE WHEN row_nbr = 2 THEN HRHX.N_VALUE END), '#.00') as prevFTE
from HrHist
where rownum <= 2
group by HrHist.EMPLOYEE
```

I say probably because parts of your queston disagree with others/you talk about fields that aren't present

Anyway.. Max and Min won't give you the current and previous values, they will give the max and min values. If the current value of X is less than the prev value, then MAX will return the prev and MIN the current..

Instead we use CASE to pick out "only the 1 [current] value" or "only the 2 [prev] value" and then use some aggregate functon like MAX to squish the nulls that result (when row_nbr is 1, then the CASE WHEN row_nbr = 2 will return null) so you get a single line per employee

It's called conditional aggregation, which is a technique used to achieve a PIVOT